# Remove spaces between dots using regex

Tags: regex

I want to remove any space that is present between two dots using regex,
for example:

`s . . . . e` --> `s .... e`

I tried replacing `\.\s+\.` to `..` but this works as following:

`s . . . . e` --> `s .. .. e`

As you can see, it finds the first match between the first and second dot, and advances to the next character after the match, and then finds a match between the third and forth dot, and so the match between the second and third dot is ignored.

How can I write my regular expression to correctly handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex [look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  as follows

```
\.\s+(?=\.)
```

And replace it with single dot(`.`) string.